# How to return another collection's data with any other collection queried?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have implemented two collections in mongo `User` and `Trainer`.

`User` collection contains id, name, email, and description.
and `Trainer` contains id, coursesMade, and trainerId. here trainerId is the id from the User collection
example :

```
//User collection
{
  id:123,
  name: "alice",
  email: "alice@example.com",
  description: "some text"
}

//Trainer collection
{
  id:134,
  coursesMade: 3,
  trainerId: 123
}
```

now I have some function that gives me a list of trainers.
I want to have a query that returns me trainer collection as well as the user reference of that trainerId.

expected output:

```
{
  id:134,
  coursesMade: 3,
  trainerId: 123,
  trainerDetails: {
    id: 123,
    name: "alice",
    email: "alice@example.com",
    description: "some text"
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to implement this in mongo as a beginner,
any general idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use lookup

```
db.trainer.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "trainerId",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "trainers"
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9j4mSFYbNzj)